# Can a Wi-Fi extender operate as gateway; not just repeater

Tags: wireless-networking

By saying this I mean a mode of operation when AP in question connects to Wi-Fi network "A", -- as a host, -- and at same time it defines own Wi-Fi network "B"; clients of "B" are routed to "A" (typically with NAT).

I have TP-Link Wi-Fi extender wired with OpenWRT now but my gets are telling me "route mode" isn't typical and its support would require 2 radio tracts. Does a typical Wi-Fi repeater has 2?

Do such production built devices exists at all?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's sort that out a bit. There are several modes of operation for an "extender":

1) One way of operation is to just retransmit the frames it receives, unchanged. In this mode, the repeater has no presence in the WLAN, no IP address, and no MAC address (though often the repeater acts *in* addition as a client with those addresses, to be able to present a webinterface etc.) No NAT happens. Only one radio stack is needed.

2) An extender can also act as an AP in a [wireless distribution systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system) (WDS). The problem with WDS is that the standard is a bit fuzzy and allows different implementations. On top of that, there are proprietary implementations that are incompatible with each other.

Normally, communication between a single AP and its clients only involves three MAC addresses in the wireless communication frame. But forwarding frames between different APs needs four MAC addresses (original source, original destination, sending AP, receiving AP), so to make a "real" WDS, *all* participating APs need to switch to four-address mode. You'll typically enable this mode using a `WDS` option or similar in the APs webinterface. The forwarding then just happens on OSI level 3, the packet never leaves the network interface, there are no IP addresses involved, only MAC addresses, and again, no NAT happens. Only one radio stack is needed.

3) A third way of operation is for the extender to act both as an independent AP, and at the same time as a client to the main AP. This requires two *network interfaces*, but not necessarily two radio stacks: Most modern single-channel Wifi hardware is perfectly capable of supporting several interfaces on just one radio. On Linux (and most routers are embedded Linux systems), `iw phy` will tell you about these capabilities under the *valid interface combinations* heading.

This is the worst mode of operation, because now you have essentially two independent APs on the same channel competing with each other, and because of the [hidden station problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem), undetected collisions can happen, which reduce overall throughput in addition to the necessary repitition of packets.

So while two radio stacks are not *necessary*, everything runs a lot smoother if the extender can use two different channels. But two radio stacks that can deal with different channels at once are expensive, you won't find them often in hardware, therefore most extenders won't use this mode.

This is also the only mode where the extender actually acts as a gateway and does NAT.

You can set up this mode in OpenWRT, but it's much better to use one of the other modes, or keep the old firmware and use proprietary modes by TP-Link (if all your hardware is TP-Link).

Comment: Nice try; but try to keep up with the question. Headline was "Can a Wi-Fi extender operate as gateway; not just repeater" — where's your answer? Also, you said 3rd mode is the worst, but from your reply it doesn't seem so to me; it's bad only if chip is cheap: "But two radio stacks that can deal with different channels at once are expensive". I'm okay with finding something that would work this way

Comment: The answer is: "yes, if it's the sort of extender that operates in in the third mode, then it operates as gateway. Otherwise, it doesn't.". See text: "This is also the only mode where the extender actually **acts as a gateway**". I only know PC hardware where one wifi card can actually control two channels, and even there, it's just a few devices. I looked for routers that can do it, because that would have been convenient for something I wanted to do, but couldn't find any. If you find some, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done without two radios. Network "B" will have to use the same channel as network "A" if they share the radio. The only multiple radio devices I am aware of have one 2.4GHz and one 5GHz radio. Two radios in the same band would have to have much more engineering involved to prevent them from interfering with each other. I have a ASUS WL-330gE which does what you describe in stock firmware. I haven't used OpenWRT, so I don't know details of how to set it up, but I am confident that it is possible.

Comment: This is the mode that dirkt describes under 3)